# iOS: Changing min SDK Version of App in Apple's Store

Tags: iphone, ios5, sdk, app-store, ios5.1

I have released an App in the App Store with target platform 5.1. The app also was developed using SDK 5.1. My customer phoned me and said this is crap because als the jailbroken phones aren't able to download the app yet - because there is currently no jailbroken version for 5.1.

What do I have to do? I'm coming from Android - therefore I want to be really sure what I am doing when applying an App update to ensure that it is also available for 5.0 users.

I also use a Library Project - which also uses SDK 5.1 as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: My App SDK]

I would be really glad about some instructions how to reduce the required version for the app and if there are some compatibility troubles/problems occurring to my code when I do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change the deployment target, in the summary tab of the target, as shown in the image:

[image: Set deployment target]

And call your customer and tell him there is already Jailbreak for 5.1 ;)

Comment: Is that all I have to do? Do I have to do the same for the SDWebImage - or is this enough. And when I set to 4.3 there are no problems with Storyboards etc. ?

Comment: You have to do it for the target you are building for.
Storyboards are available since iOS 5, so you will have to choose what you prefer. IMHO, iOS 5 has a extremely high percentage of use, and with the launch of iOS 6 in a few months, you shouldn't worry about iOS 4 (let alone for JB or a customer that thinks there is no JB for 5.x)

Answer (score 1):

Release App version 1.1 with **deployment Target OS as 5.0** or what ever else version you want to include ...

Answer (score 0):

Just found this now while researching another question, so I'm sure this has already been handled, but here's my $0.02, eight years later....

You provided a working app to the App Store. All apps on the App Store are guaranteed to work on compatible iPhones that have *not* been jailbroken.

If your user is doing non-sanctioned things with his iPhone, it's not really your concern. There were plenty of big-name apps which had the same problem as yours: people couldn't use the latest version because a jailbreak wasn't yet available. They had to wait until such a jailbreak was out. That's the risk you take with using a jailbreak.

The difference here is that if FaceBook or WhatsApp or whatever big-name app changed its target SDK to an iOS version that did not yet have a jailbreak, users couldn't call Zuckerberg on the phone to complain or threaten. You, as an independent developer, got the phone call.

It's a balancing act. You want to use the latest, greatest features of the iOS version, but existing users might not have the latest, greatest OS. So you have to decide what's more important: new features or supporting existing users.